# Estou com o seguinte erro no meu código "Illegal modifier for the local class Ponto; only abstract or final is permitted code: 16777522"

Tags: java, classes, public

Não manjo muito de Java e tenho um trabalho da facul para entregar, e só preciso alinhar este código.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    public class Ponto {
        private double x, y;

        public Ponto() {
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }

        public Ponto(double x, double y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void mover(double x, double y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public double getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public double getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public double distancia() {
            double distancia;
            distancia = (double) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            return distancia;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Ponto (" + x + "," + y + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Você declarou a classe `Ponto` dentro da função `main()` então o modificador de acesso `public` nesse caso é redundante pois fazendo assim a classe existe apenas dentro do escopo da função `main()`. Para fazer o código funcionar apenas remova o modificador de acesso, veja https://ideone.com/lLxdbm

Comment: Talvez manter a classe `Ponto` restrita ao escopo da função `main` não seja o que pretendia fazer, pode o ser mais interessante mover a declaração da classe `Ponto` para fora da declaração da classe `Main`, veja https://ideone.com/LrwAi4

Answer (score -2):

Testando aqui não encontrei nenhum erro de sintaxe no seu código, porém acredito ser incomum criar uma classe dentro da Main.
O que fiz para o código funcionar foi apenas criar uma classe Ponto.java e utilizá-la na Main.java trazendo o valor de x apenas para testar.
Segue os códigos presentes em cada arquivo para consulta:

Ponto.java

```java
public class Ponto {
  private double x, y;

  public Ponto() {
      x = 0;
      y = 0;
  }

  public Ponto(double x, double y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
  }

  public void mover(double x, double y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
  }

  public double getX() {
      return x;
  }

  public double getY() {
      return y;
  }

  public double distancia() {
      double distancia;
      distancia = (double) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
      return distancia;
  }

  public String toString() {
      return "Ponto (" + x + "," + y + ")";
    }
}
```

Main.java

```java
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ponto ponto = new Ponto();
    System.out.println(ponto.getX());
  }
}
```